# Specify ticks as micro seconds

Tags: pgfplots, ticks

I am trying to create a tick which uses e-6 as x axis. Now it automatically scales to e-5.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
        width=15cm,
        height=7cm,
        title=Motor terminal voltage as function of rise time for various cable lenghts,
        minor x tick num =5,
        minor y tick num = 1,
        anchor=origin,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.5pt,draw=gray!75},
        minor grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!40},
        xlabel = Rise time \lbrack\SI{}{\micro\second}\rbrack, 
        ylabel = Motor terminal voltage \lbrack p.u.\rbrack, 
        xmax=20e-6, 
        xmin=0,
        %xtick= {0, 0.000001, ...,0.000004}
        ]

        \addplot [black,thick, domain=-1e-6:3.715e-6, samples=10, forget plot]  {2 } ;


        \addplot [
        black,thick, dotted,variable=\X, 
        restrict y to domain = -1:2, 
        domain=0:20e-6, samples=500] 
        {((3 * 0.010 * 0.999) / (\X * 1/sqrt(0.2414e-3*0.615e-6))) +1 } ;

        \addplot [
        black, thick, dashed,variable=\X,
        restrict y to domain = -1:2, 
        domain=0:20e-6, samples=500] 
        {((3 * 0.050 * 0.995) / (\X * 1/sqrt(0.2414e-3*0.615e-6))) +1 } ;

        \addplot [
        black,thick, solid,variable=\X, 
        restrict y to domain = -1:2, 
        domain=0:20e-6, samples=500] 
        {((3 * 0.10 * 0.9898) / (\X * 1/sqrt(0.2414e-3*0.615e-6))) +1 } ;


        \addlegendentry{10 meter cable}
        \addlegendentry{50 meter cable}
        \addlegendentry{100 meter cable}


        legend pos = north east,
        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

What is the trick to solve this?

Comment: Why don't you just name your units [ps] (picoseconds)? Or do you actually mean 10^-6 [s] (seconds)?

Comment: I do mean micro seconds. I specify it in the axis label to emphasize it in case people doesnt notice the other one at the right hand side.

Comment: I would strongly advise against that, since it is not only confusing to people who *do* pay attention to your axis labels, but it's also plain wrong. I would leave out the $\cdot 10^-6$ altogether and specify the [µs] only - nobody's going to skip over your unit designation since it's right next to the axis label.

Comment: I would also like to leave out the automatic dot-10^-6, but right now I'm not sure how as it appears automatically.

Comment: That's because your equation and plot range are in seconds. Multiplying everything by 10^6 should work.

Comment: I consider that a hack. It would rather use some kind of option to disable it from the axis environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If fixed it using the following options to the axis environment:

```
scaled x ticks=base 10:6,
/pgf/number format/sci subscript,
```

Full working example below with output:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

        \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[
        scaled x ticks=base 10:6,
        /pgf/number format/sci subscript,
        width=15cm,
        height=7cm,
        title=Motor terminal voltage as function of rise time for various cable lenghts,
        minor x tick num =5,
        minor y tick num = 1,
        anchor=origin,
        grid=both,
        grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=gray!10},
        major grid style={line width=.5pt,draw=gray!75},
        minor grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=gray!40},
        xlabel = Rise time \lbrack\SI{}{\micro\second}\rbrack, 
        ylabel = Motor terminal voltage \lbrack p.u.\rbrack, 
        xmax=20e-6, 
        xmin=0,
        %xtickten={-6}
        %xtick={1e-6}
        ]

        \addplot [black,thick, domain=-1e-6:3.715e-6, samples=10, forget plot]  {2 } ;


        \addplot [
        black,thick, dotted,variable=\X, 
        restrict y to domain = -1:2, 
        domain=0:20e-6, samples=500] 
        {((3 * 0.010 * 0.999) / (\X * 1/sqrt(0.2414e-3*0.615e-6))) +1 } ;

        \addplot [
        black, thick, dashed,variable=\X,
        restrict y to domain = -1:2, 
        domain=0:20e-6, samples=500] 
        {((3 * 0.050 * 0.995) / (\X * 1/sqrt(0.2414e-3*0.615e-6))) +1 } ;

        \addplot [
        black,thick, solid,variable=\X, 
        restrict y to domain = -1:2, 
        domain=0:20e-6, samples=500] 
        {((3 * 0.10 * 0.9898) / (\X * 1/sqrt(0.2414e-3*0.615e-6))) +1 } ;


        \addlegendentry{10 meter cable}
        \addlegendentry{50 meter cable}
        \addlegendentry{100 meter cable}


        legend pos = north east,
        \end{axis}

        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]